# PHPStorm can't open js file

Tags: javascript, svn, phpstorm

I'm using SVN 1.7 with a PHPStorm project and today I've created a js file in my project then a while after I deleted it. I created it again later and I couldn't open it at all.

It has a small question mark next to its file name, and nothing happens if I try to open it in PHPStorm. (I can create new files next to it with same extension and they don't have this problem).

[image: Screenshot]

I can open it using external tools (notepad++, etc), I can delete it from PHPStorm as well.

Other people using my SVN repository can open it. I tried to create new project from the repository into new folder, but the problem was still there for that single file.

Comment: http://oi62.tinypic.com/s5dc9l.jpg

Comment: I actually renamed it and I could open it, but why the heck I can't use it with the original name

Comment: actually I can't open any of my files with the same name + extension

Comment: Not sure about this "question mark" icon. My suggestion -- `Settings | File Types` -- go trough each entry and check every pattern - maybe you do have your file name as one of them...

Answer (score 5):

I think I have a solution to this. I had a similar problem in my PHPStorm configuration. If you clear PHPStorm's cache in File->Invalidate Caches/Restart menu option, it will again let you open the file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y7sS.png

Comment: Works like a charm for my WebStorm 11. For HTML files and all other, i think, will work too. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same problem today and it turns out that when I was creating a new file, I have added the exact file name in the list of file type's registered patterns. In my case, I added it to "H2 Database File".

I don't know how I could have made the mistake but sure enough, when I looked at **Settings > File Types** and looked for the icon in the list of recognized file types (in your case, a question mark), I saw the file name in the registered pattern section. I deleted it and I was able to open the file again.

It took me a lot of time to fix this so I hope this will help future users.